# Pagination - First, Next, Previous, Last

Tags: php, pagination

I'm having a small issue with my pagination,

I've been struggling trying to attach a working First, Next Previous and Last links, I've spent the past two days searching on Google but I've been unable to find a workable solution

```
<div>
<?php for($x = max(1, $page - 5); $x <= min($page + 5, $pages); $x++): ?>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="?page=<?php echo $x; ?>"<?php if ($page === $x) ?>><?php echo $x; ?></a></li>
</ul>
<?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

For example [First] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [Next >>] ... [<< Previous] [95] [96] [97] [98] [99] [Last]

If anyone could help it would be most appreciated.

Comment: So what is the specific issue with that code above you posted? Does it work? Not work? If not, what _is_ the issue?

Comment: @arkascha - the code works, no issue with that, the issue I'm having is how to go about extending the code to add a First, Next, Previous and Last links along with adding the last 5 page links to the end as currently only the first 6 pages show up.

Comment: There is a pagination class: https://codecanyon.net/item/php-pagination-class/72158 even if you decide to "roll your own" you can still take some guidance from the class to see how its done.

Comment: I don't understand the issue you describe. Sure, those "special" links have to be added to the numeric list of pages, but what is the issue with that? You have to do it.

Comment: @Chris - Thanks very much, it's just what I needed :)

Comment: No problem, you should look over the code and try to understand it so that you know exactly what its doing. That way you can learn how to do it yourself should you ever need to.